# How to make gear constraints that work both ways?

Tags: constraints

I have this gear setup:

[image: gears]

I call the top gear the Rack and the bottom gear the Pinion.

I can set a Transformation constraint up so that if I spin the rack, the pinion spins too (in the correct direction at the correct rate). I can also set it up so that, if I spin the pinion, the rack spins too.

However, I cannot do both at the same time. I cannot set it up such that spinning the rack spins the pinion AND spinning the pinion spins the rack; I have to choose one or the other.

In essence, I can only have one "drive" gear, and the other gear is merely passive.

How do I configure my constraints so that spinning either gear spins the other one?

Comment: I don't think such "loops" are allowed. Suppose you rotate X by 1°, rotation is copied to Y. But  if X depends on Y rotation too. as Y has been rotated by 1°, X should be rotated too by 1° (2°), and so on...to infinity and beyond! Luckily Blender just don't rotate anything, preventing crashes. This two constrains can't work together. Wouldn't be possible to link them both to a third "controller" object (e.g an empty)?